# Ubuntu SQL Server Restoration

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, restore

I am trying to restore a `SQL database` using `.bak` file on an `Ubuntu` server where `SQL Developers` is installed.

I used the following command line:

> **sqlcmd** *-S localhost,1433 -U SA -Q "RESTORE VERIFYONLY JCIHistorianDB
>   FROM DISK = '/home/test_db.bak' WITH MOVE 'testDB_Data' TO
>   '/var/opt/mssql/data/test_db.mdf', MOVE 'testDB_Log' TO
>   '/var/opt/mssql/data/test_db.ldf'"*

As per following, the result is successful:

**RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 528668 pages in 845.191 seconds**

However the database data is around **half of the size** it should be. It's not coming from the `.bak` file as the restoration from the same file on a windows instance was all good.

Do you have any ideas why this happened? I also have enough space on the `Ubuntu Server`.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you did a `restore verifyonly` operation, that shouldn't have restored a database at all. That command is for verifying the integrity of the backup file (i.e. SQL Server reads the backup file as though going through a restore, but doesn't do anything with the database. Try replacing `verifyonly` with `database` in your command.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake when copy the query, I used the command:  sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE JCIHistorianDB FROM DISK = '/home/test_db.bak' WITH MOVE 'testDB_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test_db.mdf', MOVE 'testDB_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test_db.ldf'"

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is that the backup is not what you think it is (i.e. it's not from the point in time you think it is). You should be able to check restorehistory and backupset (both in msdb) for relevant properties of the backup set that you restored.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you I was able to resolve the issue, you where right concerning the backup I was missing some data since the date of the generation was wrong.